# Is there any way to launch iOS MAUI app the classical way, same way as it was with Xamain.iOS, with storyboard, omitting any xaml pages?

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, maui

MAUI is actively evolving these days and lots of tutorials appear every day, however, as the main focus is multi-platform, there is almost no specific details about running native apps in classical way, like it was with **Xamarin.iOS** natively.

So, my main question is actually about how I can **launch my MAUI app using a Storyboard**, with no xaml pages etc. use (unless there is no other way (at least for the first steps before the Storyboard displayed))?

*This is actually a broad question. In context of retiring Xamarin, that seems that it's gonna be quite important question about how to migrate from Xamarin Native (iOS also) projects (which use Storyboards and (possibly) Views) to MAUI. And I can't see any references to that anywhere!*

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT, wow! Thanks for the comment! There IS such template indeed (although it was hard to find it even after your hint (it appeared at the very end of the list even after filtering by iOS/Mobile))!
And having separate project for that is totally fine, I guess. However, the idea of having ability to run the apps "in native way" with the new architecture of MAUI might still have sense. Could you guide me where is the best to post such questions to MAUI community for further discussions?

Comment: For bug report or feature request, you could open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what you want is *Microsoft.iOS*, namely *.Net for iOS*. *Microsoft.iOS* is the successor to native *Xamarin.iOS* and it is the important non-Forms foundation of MAUI.

In *Visual Studio 2022 (for Mac)*, you could find the *.NET for iOS* template which is called *iOS Application*. For migration from Xamarin Native projects, you could refer to [.NET MAUI Migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/).

Second, if you want to ask how-to questions, Stack overflow itself is a good place.

But for bug reports or feature requests, you could open an issue on GitHub:

[Maui issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui)

[.Net macOS,iOS... issues](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios)

Hope it helps!